# How to accept only number for phone in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I think it might be silly question but trust me I am new to react. I am working on form there I am using `<input type="number"/>` here I am achieving number goal ( I mean it will just accept number ) but I want to put some limitation mean that user will not able to enter more then 8 characters. I want to accept only number and limit 8 could some please help me ?

Comment: `<input type=tel >` or `pattern=^\d{7,8}$`

Comment: What have you tried? Did you do any research before asking? If so what did you find?

Comment: @BrianThompson Yes , I already did . actually I want to take phone number and it will be only accept number not other characters , also I want character limit means that I want to allow user to enter just 8 characters

Comment: @dandavis it accept alphabetic values too. I just want numeric value

Comment: Is this a controlled input?

Comment: I just wan to accept numeric value and it should be limit of 8 . Actually I am using for phone number

Comment: Yes I understand that. But is it a controlled or uncontrolled input. Do you store its value in state and update it with an `onChange` handler? You tagged this as react, but you haven't given any react code to go off of. Ultimately this needs more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a controlled input here is how you might do it.

We'll use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regex that only allows digits. *If you don't care about supporting IE you can skip this and just rely on the `type="number"`.*

Then we'll use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with a starting position of 0 and an end of 8 since you want to limit to 8 digits. If you need something different than 8, just change this number.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  }
   
  onChange = e => {
    // Separated into 3 steps for clarity
    let onlyNumbers = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    let limitToEight = onlyNumbers.slice(0, 8);

    this.setState({ value: limitToEight });

    // In one line:
    // this.setState({ value: e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').slice(0, 8) })
  }
  
  render() {
    return <input type='number' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Comment: How to limit characters ? I want to accept only 8 characters

Comment: Did you run the snippet? It limits to 8. `.slice(0,8)`

Answer (score 1):

Just add pattern and maxlength attribute to it.

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="8"/>
```

If you want to use the number only, use as follows:

```html
<input type="number" pattern="/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==8) return false;" />
```

Comment: it accepting alphabetic value too I just want numeric value and limit

Comment: it give me error, please update your answer for react

Comment: @Jonas can you be more specific about the error you're getting?

Comment: @Gabriel I tried but nothing happen 

onKeyPress={e => {
                  let { value } = e.target;
                  if (value.length < 8) {
                    return value;
                  }
                }}

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the characters if they are less than limit set state, if greater don't set state.

```
handleInput = e => {
  e.persist();

  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      input: e.target.value.length < 9 ? e.target.value : prevState.input
    };
  });
};
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input: ""
  };

  handleInput = e => {
    e.persist();

    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        input: e.target.value.length < 9 ? e.target.value : prevState.input
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={this.state.input}
          type="number"
          onChange={this.handleInput}
        />
        <p>typed: {this.state.input}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```